# Spring bean loading order

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've two bean definitions in my application-context.xml (BeanClassA, BeanClassB). If BeanClassA has an @Autowired annotation to BeanClassB, Should the BeanClassB be declared BEFORE BeanClassA in the bean definitions in application-context.xml? More generically is there an inherent order in which the beans would be loaded..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Unless you have some complex circular dependencies, Spring will be able to publish all injections before making any beans available to you. The order of declarations in XML is not important.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sotirios, When I specify it in the current order i.e. BeanClassB declared AFTER BeanClassA, I sporadically see a NoSuchBeanDefinitionFoundException, could this in anyway be connected to the way they are being loaded. I suspect that sometimes the BeanClassA tries to load without having loaded BeanClassB first into the BeanFactory.

Comment: @looseseal_90 No. You have something else going on. I suggest you ask another question with all the relevant details. (Or edit this one, but don't get in the habit of completely changing your question.)

Comment: I'll try to give a more detailed overview of the problem in a new question. The error I see sometimes is the BeanClassB autowiring failed with a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException, this works most of the time but not all.. which is why I thought it might have to do with load order.. Thanks anyways!!

Comment: Do your best to provide an MCVE. Declaration order should not make any different. However, for complex injection scenarios (and depending on the type of bean (`BeanPostProcessor`, etc.), the order in which Spring initializes everything can be problematic if you aren't careful. But a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionFoundException` means something entirely different.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, I've provided the MCVE in a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633269/sporadic-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-when-trying-to-autowire-field. Thanks again for your response.