# Sporadic NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when trying to autowire field

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've my application-config.xml defined as follows,

```
...
<beans>
   <bean id="serviceFactory" class="com.example.MyServiceFactory" />
   <bean id="myAction" class="com.example.MyAction" scope="request">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
   </bean>
   <bean id="myService" class="com.example.MyService" factory-bean="serviceFactory" factory-method="getService">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="myServiceConfig" />
   </bean>
</beans>
...
```

As you can see, the 'myAction' bean is request scoped and in my MyAction file I've the following.

```
public class MyAction
{
    @Autowired
    protected MyService myService;
}
...
```

Sometimes, not always, I see that the autowiring of the dependency myService fails. I can't figure out if it has to do in some way with the way I've defined in the application-context.xml or if this has to do with something else. Could someone help me out here?

EDIT1:

Spring log says

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myAction': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.example.MyService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.example.MyService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Not much of an MCVE here. We need something reproducible or at least complete. What is your configuration? What are your bean types? What do your Spring logs say (enable DEBUG)? Etc.

Comment: The spring logs just say this.. the stacktrace is in `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
    No qualifying bean of type [com.example.MyService] found for dependency:
    expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
    Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)`

Comment: All we can do at the moment is link to the javadoc of [NoSuchBeanDefinitionException](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.html), which states _Exception thrown when a BeanFactory is asked for a bean instance for which it cannot find a definition._ Without seeing your configuration and/or the corresponding beans, we can only guess and that's a poor way to answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little new to Spring, when you say configuration and the beans and bean types? what do you mean other than type and bean definitions in application-context.xml.

Comment: Your XML file is your Spring context configuration. If Spring is throwing `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, that means it cannot find a bean. Either you haven't defined it in your context configuration or you've defined it but haven't pointed Spring to the right place.

Comment: Ok, i've the context file that I'm using pasted at the top. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Sure, but how do you use it? You've tagged `spring-mvc`. Where do you load it? In the `DispatcherServlet`? In the `ContextLoaderListener`? What's in between? [Here's how to prepare and produce an MCVE.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Failing that, we can't really help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79597/discussion-between-looseseal-90-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: You found any solution to the issue? Have seen the same behaviour a couple of times for one bean.

Comment: The problem fixed itself. I think it was due to an incorrect component-scan..

Comment: @looseseal_90 but shouldn't it then always fail? You have more insight into what was wrong about your component-scan?